# Youtube Data API v3 video uploaded is not processed for HD

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have successfully uploaded a video using Youtube Data API v3 insert, however, the video uploaded is not being processed for HD. Only SD is available. The following parameters are set in code:

```
body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
      title=options.title,
      description=options.description,
      tags=tags,
      categoryId=options.category
    ),
    status=dict(
      privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus
    ),
    recordingDetails=dict(
      recordingDate=options.recordingDate
    ),
    contentDetails=dict(
      definition='hd'
    )
  )
```

Comment: When you upload the same video manually does it get processed as HD?

Comment: Yes it does. Interesting fact is as i removed the credential and re-authorized, it started working fine. Do not know if that was for some limited scope I had or not. But thank you @RandomDavis its after reading your comment, struck me to remove the credential file and retry. :)

Comment: I met this issue as well. I tried to remove the stored credentials and re-authenticate, no success. My HD video is converted to 1080p when uploaded to Youtube via Data API v3.
If I upload the same video file manually via web UI, it is displayed in high definition.

Comment: Running into a similar issue... When I upload my 4k video via API it only gets encoded in SD. When I upload it manually, it encodes in 4k... Not sure what to change about the API settings to allow it to upload in higher qualities...

Comment: Nevermind, in my case it was just that YouTube doesn't show that it's processing the HD versions and it takes longer. When I check the next day, the uploaded videos do have the HD version.