# Videos uploaded via YouTube Data API v3 only processed in SD, not HD

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been trying to upload videos via the API but they only ever get processed in SD.

When I upload the same video manually via YouTube Studio, it gets processed for SD, HD and 4K no problem.

Here's how I'm doing it:

```php
    public function uploadVideo(YoutubeVideo $videoData): void
    {
        $this->configureClient($videoData->channelId);

        $video = $this->createVideo($videoData);
        $this->client->setDefer(true);
        $insertRequest = $this->youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet,contentDetails", $video);

        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $this->client,
            $insertRequest,
            'video/*',
            null,
            true,
            self::CHUNKSIZE
        );
        $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoData->filename));

        // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
        $status = false;
        $handle = fopen($videoData->filename, "rb");
        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
            $chunk = fread($handle, self::CHUNKSIZE);
            $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
        }

        fclose($handle);

        $this->client->setDefer(false);
    }

    private function createVideo(YoutubeVideo $videoData): Google_Service_YouTube_Video
    {
        $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
        $snippet->setTitle($videoData->title);
        $snippet->setDescription($videoData->description);
        $snippet->setTags($videoData->tags);
        $snippet->setCategoryId($videoData->category);

        $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
        $status->privacyStatus = $videoData->status;

        $contentDetails = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoContentDetails();
        $contentDetails->setDefinition('hd');

        $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
        $video->setSnippet($snippet);
        $video->setStatus($status);
        $video->setContentDetails($contentDetails);

        return $video;
    }
```

I tried what was suggested in the comments of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63959174/youtube-data-api-v3-video-uploaded-is-not-processed-for-hd), re-authenticating my app, but no change.

Is there something else I'm missing to enable HD for uploads? Maybe I'm missing some permission in the Google API Console?

Comment: That's kind of new API behavior. I guess that your app was not audited yet. I suggest to file an issue report to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/). Also, please link back that here, so that other interested SO users to find it easily.

Comment: I forgot to mention: as far as I know, the API has no options w.r.t. *enabling HD uploads*; neither the Console has *special permissions* for that matter. My guess is that Google introduced tacitly a new restriction w.r.t. uploading videos under projects created before 28 July 2020 (the projects created after 28 July 2020 [need to be verified](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#note) for allowing uploaded videos be public).

Comment: Thanks @stvar - I was going to file an issue, but this morning I check the uploaded videos again and they actually have been processed in full HD and 4K quality. They just didn't show that they were processing in those qualities yesterday (they show that processing status when uploaded manually, but not via API). I guess the processing takes longer for videos done via API, but it looks like they do actually get processed eventually.